# How should I handle tall grass patches in my lawn?

Tags: lawn, grass, mowing

I recently purchased a home in January. Now that it's Spring the grass is starting to come through. However, I've noticed a variety of grass patches of different colors and lengths before I mowed for the first time:
[image: Before Mowing]

I assumed this was because I had waited too long to mow my lawn (truthfully, I did). However, after mowing for the first time I noticed these grass patches were yellowish:
[image: After Mowing]

After reading online it seems like if your grass is too yellow after mowing it means you cut it too low, but the rest of my lawn is perfectly fine, so that leads me to believe that this grass is something that shouldn't be there.

Should I dig these patches up and re-seed? If not, how should I deal with these?

Comment: Could you show a close up picture of the green areas and the yellow areas? I am guessing that perhaps they might be different varieties/species.

Comment: @Viv - Sure, I'll have that tomorrow (dark out now). The images weren't originally intended for this purpose, only after reading online did I realize I might need to do something about the patches, but I think they should be high enough now to see some detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd simply mow it a few more times before freaking out and "weeding" it out. It may just be yellow now because it was taller before you mowed, so the lower parts were more shaded. Could be those patches had excess fertilizer, causing the higher growth. Mow it to the same length for a while and see if the color evens out.

Comment: Looks like this solved the issue, after mowing my lawn a few more times and keeping up with it, things all appear a consistent shade of green.